# ZXing - Using the generic type BarcodeWriter<TOutput> requires 1 type argument ZXing.NET.Mobile

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, zxing

I have been trying to generate a QRCode using ZXing.Net.Mobile and ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms: 
https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile and have come across the following error:

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0305  Using the generic type 'BarcodeWriter' requires 1 type arguments   TestApp.Android G:\Tests\TestApp\TestApp\TestApp.Android\SelectedBookingPage.cs 70  Active
"

This is my code:

```
BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter()
            {
                Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
                Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
                {
                    Height = 600,
                    Width = 600
                }
            };
```

Other examples I have seen call BarcodeWriter() like above just fine, https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/ZXing/BarcodeWriter/-/php-barcodewriter-class-examples.html to list a few.

Why does calling BarcodeWriter require a type argument. How can I properly instansiate an instance of a BarcodeWriter?

Answer (score 8):

If you use ZXing.Net with .Net Standard, you have to add one additional package with a specific implementation of the barcode reader and writer classes for the image manipulation library that you want to use.

On Windows for example, you need to use this package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Bindings.Windows.Compatibility/

more info here:
https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/issues/370

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue. BarcodeWriter can be instantiated as expected when used natively in the android project, in my original question I was attempting to use it within the cross platform Xamarin part of the project.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using BarcodeWriter from the wrong namespace.

You should be using `ZXing.Mobile.BarcodeWriter` whereas you are using `ZXing.BarcodeWriter`, try the below and see if that works for you:

```
var barcodeWriter = new ZXing.Mobile.BarcodeWriter
        {
            Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
            Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
            {
                Height = 600,
                Width = 600
            }
        };
```

Comment: When I try that I get the following error:
The type or namespace name 'BarcodeWriter' does not exist in the namespace 'ZXing.Mobile'. It seems the namespace only contains items related to MobileBarcodeScanner.

Comment: You should try using the version `2.3.2` of ZXing