# Questions on c# ZXing libaray to use KeyboardHook

Tags: c#, zxing, barcode-scanner, keyboard-hook, zxing.net

First, I am a c# new learner, so my question might be very simple one.
I am trying to make a program that reading code 128(barcode form) and change this barcode to just regular letter.
Even though I have installed ZXing.Net package using Nuget, there exists an red line on 'BarcodeReader'. How can I solve this probelm? The error shows "Using the generic type 'BarcodeReader' requires 1 type argument."

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ZXing; 

namespace KeyboardHook_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        private delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        const int VK_RETURN = 0x0D;

        private IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetHook();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            RemoveHook();
        }

        private string _currentBarcode = string.Empty;
        private bool _isBarcodeInput = false;

        private string ParseBarcode(string barcodeData)
        {
            // Parse the code 128 barcode data and convert it to text
            // For example, you can use a library like ZXing.Net to parse the barcode data

            var reader = new BarcodeReader
            {
                Options =
        {
            PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.CODE_128 }
        },
                AutoRotate = true
            };

            var result = reader.Decode(barcodeData);
            if (result != null)
            {
                return result.Text;
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }

        private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                if (vkCode == VK_RETURN) // check for the Enter key
                {
                    if (_isBarcodeInput)
                    {
                        // Parse the barcode value and display it
                        string barcode = ParseBarcode(_currentBarcode);
                        MessageBox.Show("Barcode read: " + barcode);
                        _currentBarcode = string.Empty;
                        _isBarcodeInput = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Add the input to the current barcode value
                    _currentBarcode += (char)vkCode;
                    _isBarcodeInput = true;
                }
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        private void SetHook()
        {
            using (Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule currentModule = currentProcess.MainModule)
            {
                IntPtr hModule = LoadLibrary("User32.dll");
                _hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookCallback, hModule, 0);
            }
        }

        private void RemoveHook()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ZXing - Using the generic type BarcodeWriter<TOutput> requires 1 type argument ZXing.NET.Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54917300/zxing-using-the-generic-type-barcodewritertoutput-requires-1-type-argument-z)